# Matlab - usage of workspace variables

Tags: matlab

I want to create a function `function ExtremePoints = AnalyseData( ScanData )`.

I want to be able to run the function without passing the argument ScanData, and in this situation I want to use a variable with the same name from Matlab Workspace.

Is this possible, to use inside the body of the function the variable ScanData which appear  in workspace?

Or should I first save the content of the variable ScanData from workspace into a .mat file and then load that file in the body of the function?

Comment: As @Edric already mentions: it is (strongly) discouraged to do so, as you will not be able to properly reuse the function somewhere else without much pain (missing variables, something completely different stored in `ScanData`, less clear code, mlint will not warn you for your mistakes inside `eval` or `evalin`, ...). So do yourself a favor and refrain from using these when you don't have to!

Comment: The thing is that the mentioned function is used more as a test script and instead of launching the call from Command Window, I want to call the function directly from the editor and that's the reason for asking this question. Thanks for the advice though! :)

Comment: there are some different things you can do. First of all you could make it a script instead of a function (just leave out the `function ...`). All variables will then be part of your base workspace. So this might become cluttered and you might need to play around with things like `clear variables; close all; clc;` for convenience. Or you could use the [run configurations](http://www.mathworks.cn/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-131.html#brqxeeu-136) feature. However, these are cumbersome to keep track of in version control or on different computers. So both have pros and cons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible, perhaps not entirely recommended. Here's how:

```
function ExtremePoints = AnalyseData( ScanData )
if nargin == 0
    ScanData = evalin( 'base', 'ScanData' );
end
% do stuff
```

This pulls the value of `ScanData` from the `base` workspace if no input arguments are supplied (`nargin == 0`).

Use of `eval` and `evalin` is generally discouraged as it makes your code harder to understand and re-use.